# How to override Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend?

Tags: ajax, javascript

I need to add my own little if's and checks in 3 functions inside

```
misc/ajax.js (
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend,
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.success,
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.error
)
```

How can I override them in my module? I can't find a manual and it's not in Examples for Developers. Sorry if it seems a dumb question, but I'm a php developer - I can work with js, but I'm not so fluent with it.

- Can I simply write it in my module's js file?
- If 2 or 3 modules needs to modify them, how to avoid conflicts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend` and the others are just variables that happen to have functions assigned to them. As long as your code appears in the page build *after* the original function implementations, you you should be able to just override what's already there:

```
(function($) {
  // In mymodule.js, which appears after ajax.js in the page build
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend = function(xmlhttprequest, options) {
    // Replacement code.
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: So, I'm doing it the right way, but that leaves my doubt - each module must take care to be the last one updating them on the page that needs it's changes, right? No way to prevent accidental modifications by others?

Comment: Correct, this practice is usually referred to as ['monkey patching'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) and it's not an exact science unfortunately

Comment: Oh. I was so sure there is some clean, safe, clever way I just cannot find due to my lack of js skill... I wouldn't asked if I knew. But I think I'll leave this question for future users looking for that nonexistent safe way.

Comment: Using other frameworks (Require.js, AngularJS, anything else that tries to bring Dependency Injection to Javascript) there are more satisfying ways of achieving the same results, but with plain 'ol JS/jQuery not so much. Your method is the best that I know of on top of Drupal

Answer (score 7):

This might be a better way:

```
(function ($) {
  // Drupal's core beforeSend function
  var beforeSend = Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend;
  // Add a trigger when beforeSend fires.
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend = function(xmlhttprequest, options) {
    beforeSend.call(this, xmlhttprequest, options);
    $(document).trigger('beforeSend');
  }
})(jQuery);
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/1372840