# How to alter textfield auto-submit delay?

Tags: ajax, views

I have a view with exposed filters using AJAX and auto-submit feature.

The problem is it reacts too fast, **submitting the request after every key up very fast**, so that the view is reloaded before users could finish to type search text...

I would like instead to **choose how many millisec it waits before sending request**...

Comment: Instead of this roundabout method, have you tried changing the input type for the element that the users are typing into?  It sounds like you're using an `auto-complete widget` when you should set it to plain text.  Is this the case?

Comment: @Deryck thanks and sorry for late reply I was out.. But I don't see where I could set it to basic input vs auto complete ? I need "OPERATOR CONTAINS ALL VALUES" for searching, and I'm in a view setup, not in a edit node form one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried different ways to do that, this working one was suggested by [Andy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118720/delay-ajax-call-on-textfield-to-allow-for-typing#123479) in comments to a close but different issue, thanks to him !

In fact [CTools autosubmit](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ctools/tree/js/auto-submit.js) has a hardcoded delay on submitting fixed to 500ms.

A possible way is to switch auto-submit.js to your own modified copy. *However if you do this, you'll need to check if auto-submit.js has changed every time you do an upgrade to CTools.* :

```
function neptune_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  if ($some_condition) {
    $new_autosubmit = drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOUR_THEME') . '/js/auto-submit.js';
    $javascript['profiles/commons/modules/contrib/ctools/js/auto-submit.js'] = drupal_js_defaults($new_autosubmit);
  }
}
```

And set your value into auto-submit.js :

```
//Lines 87 and following
    var timer = 3000;
          .keyup(function(e) {
            if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, discardKeyCode) === -1) {
              timeoutID = setTimeout($.proxy(triggerSubmit, this.form), timer);
            }
          })
          .bind('change', function (e) {
            if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, discardKeyCode) === -1) {
              timeoutID = setTimeout($.proxy(triggerSubmit, this.form), timer);
            }
          });
```

To be more flexible you may want to add an attribute to the input you need to change :

```
function MODULE_form_MYFORM_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['MY_INPUT']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('ctools-auto-submit-delayed'));
}
```

And then change value for this class only

```
    var timeoutID = 0;
    var timer = 500;
    if ($(this).hasClass('ctools-auto-submit-delayed')) {
      timer = 3000;
    }
    $(this)
      .bind('keydown keyup', function (e) {
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, discardKeyCode) === -1) {
          timeoutID && clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        }
      })
      .keyup(function(e) {
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, discardKeyCode) === -1) {
          timeoutID = setTimeout($.proxy(triggerSubmit, this.form), timer);
        }
      })
      .bind('change', function (e) {
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, discardKeyCode) === -1) {
          timeoutID = setTimeout($.proxy(triggerSubmit, this.form), timer);
        }
      });
```

This would be more elegant & flexible to pass directly the timer value to js, but I have no time to think more about it.

PS : there is an [existing patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2023705) about that issue but it returns errors in my config.

Comment: @andy, why should we check if auto-submit.js has changed every time you do an upgrade to CTools? I thought that `drupal_js_defaults($new_autosubmit)` would replace the original one in any case ? you mean for the hardcoded path I guess ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It _does_ replace the original one, which can be a problem. Worst case scenario, a horrible security bug is found in auto-submit.js, CTools is updated, you update CTools on your site, and the custom code above dutifully ensures that the new secure auto-submit.js is replaced with an old insecure version! Instead of a security fix it could be a new feature (eg. if that patch ever gets committed), or simply an implementation change. If there _is_ a new version, you can just copy and modify it as before. I'd keep track of it in the same place you record applied patches.

Comment: I was able to use your code snippet by copying over the Drupal.behaviors.CToolsAutoSubmit function into my theme's javascript then making my changes there. Thanks!