# Ajax callback called on textfield typing

Tags: forms, ajax, javascript

I'm trying to reach exactly the same state as autocomplete field does. When user is typing in textfield I'd like ajax to wait with its callback so the user can write all the text.

I'm trying to achieve it with help of this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118720/delay-ajax-call-on-textfield-to-allow-for-typing). But I'm failing. Maybe because I'm playing with JavaScript in drupal for the first time. Anyway here is my code.

form_alter in .module (I have form generated with features)

```
if (empty($form['nid']['#value'])) {

    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','MY_MODULE') . 'my_script.js');

    $form['field_my_field']['und'][0]['value']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => '_test_callback',
        'event' => 'finishedinput',
    );
}
```

my_script.js (from the link above)

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
Drupal.behaviors.MY_MODULE = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var typingTimer;
      var doneTypingInterval = 10;

  $('.andtimer').on('keyup', function (e) {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($(this).val) {
      var trigid = $(this);
      typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){                    
        trigid.triggerHandler('finishedinput');
      }, doneTypingInterval);
    }
  });
}
};
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

And I have script attached to my .info file.

Answer (score 4):

here my solution:

first you've to create (or alter) a text field

```
$form['user_search'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Search'),
  '#description' => t('Cool description'),
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'MODULE_ajax_user_search',
    'wrapper' => 'user-search-replace',
    'event' => 'finished_input', // custom event called by js code
    'effect' => 'fade',
  ),
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array(
      'delayed-search-submit' // custom class to attach behavior to
    ),
    'data-delay' => '300', // custom property to set submit delay
    //'data-event' => 'finished_input', // custom event name, default is "finished_input"
  ),
);
```

then you'll have to create some js code to attach to your form

```
(function($){
  $(function(){
    Drupal.behaviors.delayedSearchSubmit = {
      attach: function (context, settings) {
        $('input.delayed-search-submit').once('event', function (){
          var $self = $(this);
          var timeout = null;
          var delay = $self.data('delay');
          var triggerEvent = $self.data('event');
          if (!delay) {
            delay = 1000;
          }
          if (!triggerEvent) {
            triggerEvent = 'finished_input';
          }
          // Every time a keyup event is fired
          // timer is reset
          $self.bind('keyup', function(){
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
              $self.trigger(triggerEvent);
            }, delay);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

now attach js file to your form

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE') . '/js/MODULE.textsearch.js');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my late reaction. Still haven't found a way to reach it. I even tried to copy your code into new module. AJAX won't response anyway.

Comment: The problem with this code is that `once()` is not correctly used. `once(id)` method does not accept any callback, only `id`.

Answer (score 2):

I could not get @Kladrian version to work on Drupal 8, so I have rewrote slightly. Maybe this will help other people.

PHP `buildForm`

```
$form['user_search'] = [
  '#type'       => 'textfield',
  '#title'      => $this->t('Search'),
  '#ajax'       => [
    'callback' => [$this, 'MODULE_ajax_user_search'],
    'event'    => 'end_typing', // custom event called by custom js
    'progress' => [
      'type'    => 'throbber',
      'message' => $this->t('Searching'),
    ],
  ],
  '#attributes' => [
    'class'      => [
      'delayed-input-submit' // custom class to attach behaviour to
    ],
    'data-delay' => '500', // the delay information 
  ],
];
```

Javascript

```
(function ($, Drupal, undefined) {
  Drupal.behaviors.delayed_submit = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('input.delayed-input-submit').each(function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        var timeout = null;
        var delay = $self.data('delay') || 1000;
        var triggerEvent = $self.data('event') || "end_typing";

        $self.unbind('keyup').keyup(function () {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $self.trigger(triggerEvent);
          }, delay);
        });
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```