# Overriding Drupal.Ajax.prototype.setProgressIndicatorBar & Drupal.Ajax.prototype.success

Tags: 8, ajax

In drupal 7 you could override the drupal.ajax callbacks by replacing the code and adding it into your custom js file through a thread like this;

[How to override Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73024/how-to-override-drupal-ajax-prototype-beforesend)

However, I can't seem to find any documention for drupal 8 in modifying either of the callbacks  Drupal.Ajax.prototype.setProgressIndicatorBar or Drupal.Ajax.prototype.success.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Turns out its almost the same. Look in the ajax.js file and override your desired function: (ie. Drupal.Ajax.prototype.setProgressIndicatorThrobber)